# Restriction place Picker in certain area in Xamarin

Tags: android, xamarin, google-maps-android-api-2

I already have Place picker using  Google Maps v2 API maps been load if the condition like this:

`if (requestCode == PLACE_PICKER_REQUEST_new && resultCode == Result.Ok)
     {
         GetPlace(data);
     }`

and data been pass it to my text view like this:

```
private void GetPlace(Intent data)
    {
        var placePick = PlacePicker.GetPlace(this, data);
        placeChoose.Text =placePick?.AddressFormatted?.ToString();

    }
```

But I need to restrict the search radius for one place only for example just inside city of Kuala Lumpur and if the search beyond that it will show alert dialog. Any suggestion?

Comment: You haven't actually asked a question.

Comment: But I need to restrict the search radius for one place only for example just inside city of Kuala Lumpur and if the search beyond that it will show alert dialog. Any suggestion?

Comment: Hi, have you solved your problem? Just restrict the search radius? Do you have any demo for that, so I can do something based on yours.